# JS Отправка данных при изменении поля ввода

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть поле:

```
<input id="dir" type="text" class="i-text" name="product_dir" value="" />
```

Этот скрипт получает данные их этого поля и делает запрос к базе через php.

```
var login,dirStat;

$(function() {
$("#dir").change(function(){
    dir = $("#dir").val();

    console.log("Переменная получена");

    if (dir != null && typeof dir !== undefined) {dir = dir.trim();}
    if(!dir){
        console.log("Но она пустая");
        $("#dir").next().hide().text("Введите имя директории").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
        $("#dir").removeClass().addClass("i-text-red");
        dirStat = 0;
        buttonOnAndOff();
    }else{
        $.ajax({
        url: "testingDir.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "dir=" + dir,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);
            if(response == "no"){
                $("#dir").next().hide().text("Директория уже существует").css("color","red").fadeIn(400);
                $("#dir").removeClass().addClass("i-text-red"); 
                dirStat = 0;
                buttonOnAndOff();               
                console.log("Директория уже существует");
            }else{                  
                $("#dir").removeClass().addClass("i-text-green");
                $("#dir").next().text("");
                dirStat = 1;
                buttonOnAndOff();
                console.log("Имя свободно");
            }           

        }
    });
        dirStat = 1;
        buttonOnAndOff();
    }

});
$("#dir").keyup(function(){
    $("#dir").removeClass();
    $("#dir").next().text("");
});




function buttonOnAndOff(){
    if(emailStat == 1 && passwordStat == 1 && password2Stat == 1 && dirStat == 1){
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }else{
        $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }

}

});
```

Скрипт который транслитит ))

```
function translit(){
// Символ, на который будут заменяться все спецсимволы
var space = '-'; 
// Берем значение из нужного поля и переводим в нижний регистр
var text = $('#zagolovok').val().toLowerCase();
//var text = document.getElementById('name').value.toLowerCase();   
// Массив для транслитерации
var transl = { 
                'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'e', 'ж': 'zh', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i',
                'й': 'j', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't',
                'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h', 'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sh', 'ъ': space, 'ы': 'y',
                'ь': space, 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'yu', 'я': 'ya',

                ' ': space, '_': space, '`': space, '~': space, '!': space, '@': space, '#': space, '$': space,
                '%': space, '^': space, '&': space, '*': space, '(': space, ')': space, '-': space, '\=': space,
                '+': space, '[': space, ']': space, '\\': space, '|': space, '/': space, '.': space, ',': space,
                '{': space, '}': space, '\'': space, '"': space, ';': space, ':': space, '?': space, '<': space,
                '>': space, '№': space                  
             }

var result = '';

var curent_sim = '';

for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
    // Если символ найден в массиве то меняем его
    if(transl[text[i]] != undefined) {          
        if(curent_sim != transl[text[i]] || curent_sim != space){
            result += transl[text[i]];
            curent_sim = transl[text[i]];               
        }                   
    }
    // Если нет, то оставляем так как есть
    else {
        result += text[i];
        curent_sim = text[i];
    }       
}   

result = TrimStr(result);   

// Выводим результат
$('#dir').val(result);
//document.getElementById('alias').value = result;

}
function TrimStr(s) {
s = s.replace(/^-/, '');
return s.replace(/-$/, '');
}

// Выполняем транслитерацию при вводе текста в поле
$(function(){
$('#zagolovok').keyup(function(){
    translit();
    return false;
});
});
```

Все работает, но есть одно но, поле заполняется автоматически, скриптом, т.е.
при заполнении соседнего поля на кириллице, это поле заполняется транслитом.
И чтобы прошел запрос к базе,  мне нужно щелкнуть в это поле, добавить и удалить символ, иначе ничего не происходит.
Я так понимаю нужно сменить событие, но как?
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"это поле заполняется транслитом" - где?

При изменении значения инпута кодом событие `change` не выстреливает. Вызывайте его сами.

```
// Выводим результат
$('#dir').val(result).change();
```

```js
$("#dir").change(function(){
  console.log("From change event:", $(this).val());
});

function myClick() {
  var result = "myClick";
  // Выводим результат
  $('#dir').val(result).change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dir" type="text"/>
<button type="button" onclick="myClick()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Да, input с id dir заполняется транслитом. Где, в смысле где код транслита? ))

Comment: @Dikkiy Где код, в котором этот инпут заполняется транслитом?

Comment: сейчас будет...

Comment: не работает ((( ReferenceError: result is not defined

Comment: @Dikkiy Еще как работает! Вы неправильно скопировали мой код :).

Comment: var login,dirStat;
$(function() {
 $("#dir").change(function(){
  dir = $('#dir').val(result).change();

Comment: @Dikkiy Обратите внимание, что строчка `$('#dir').val(result).change();` в ответе идет после слов "// Выводим результат".

Comment: Замечательно, но где мне ее встроить? Результат это смена css класса в красный или зеленый в зависимости от ответа

Comment: @Dikkiy Подождите, комментарий "// Выводим результат" в Вашем коде - это Вы написали? После него и встроить.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и терпение!!! )) Всё работает!!! :))

Comment: @Dikkiy На здоровье. Я знал, что у нас с Вами все закончится хорошо!